# Maven & Junit Theories

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I want to run JUnit Theories under Maven3,
The Theories have the Annotation @Theory before the method.

Running the Tests in Eclipse makes no problem.

Running it under Maven with the surfire Plugin I get "java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods"

How can I handle this Problem

Comment: Have you configured the JUNit version maven-surefire-plugin is using ?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. My configuration in plugin section:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Junit*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludedGroups combine.self="override" />
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I used junit version 4.10

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I try to test an RCP Application with manifest first, thought that there should be no difference by running tests. So use the "tycho-surefire-plugin", so my POM looks like this: <plugins>
      <plugin>
  <!--Plugin zum ausführen von Tests-->
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

Comment: No problem, I do not have experience with tycho plugin. You can always use `maven-surefire-plugin` as maven module.

Comment: I tried to use your configuration with the maven-surfire-plugin, and surfire-junit47 but i have still the problem that the test is found but there are no runnable methods. is there any other thing i can do wrong with running theories under maven?

Comment: Problem can be that now you have two plugins and maven choose one of them. Create simple maven project and try to use `maven-surefire-plugin version 2.12` with Theories. Check include pattern